# RegEx and Excel VBA for date extraction from a filename where date can be dmmyy or ddmmyy

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I am trying to rename a set of pdf filenames in the form:
"Joe BLOGGS_3052023.pdf" or "Joe BLOGGS_31052023.pdf"
("FirstName SURNAME_dmmyy" or "FirstName SURNAME_ddmmyy").

The month is always two digits. Only the day can be either dd or d.

I need the output of the filename to be:
Joe BLOGGS_20230503.pdf or Joe BLOGGS_20230531.pdf

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim myDir As String
    myDir = "e:\Test\"
    If Dir(myDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Folder not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    SeachFiles myDir, "*.pdf"
End Sub
 

Private Sub SeachFiles(myDir, fn)
Dim fso As Object, myFolder As Object, myFile As Object
Dim temp As String, m As Object, NewName As String, OldName As String
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "(?:\D)(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})(\d{4})(?:\D)"
    .ignorecase = True
    For Each myFile In fso.getfolder(myDir).Files
        If myFile.Name Like fn Then
            If .test(myFile.Name) Then
                If Not IsFileOpen(myDir & "\" & myFile.Name) Then
                    Set m = .Execute(myFile.Name)(0)
                    temp = Format$(DateValue(m.submatches(2) & "/" & _
                      m.submatches(0) & "/" & m.submatches(1)), "yyyymmdd")
                    NewName = myDir & "\" & Application.Replace(myFile.Name, _
                      m.firstindex + 2, m.Length - 1, temp)
                    OldName = myDir & "\" & myFile.Name
                    Name OldName As NewName
                Else
                    MsgBox "Can not process " & myFile.Name & _
                      vbLf & "Currently open"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each myFolder In fso.getfolder(myDir).subfolders
        SeachFiles myFolder.Path, fn
    Next
End With
End Sub

Function IsFileOpen(fName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ff As Integer, errNum As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile
    Open fName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    errNum = Err
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsFileOpen = (errNum <> 0)
End Function
```

Here is my new code. It works BUT it looped through and did the first of 8 files twice. All the rest are fine. I don't know why it did one file again!!

```
'this function checks to see if a folder/file exists
Function FileFolderExists(sPathFile As String) As Boolean
  FileFolderExists = False
  On Error Resume Next
  If Not Dir(sPathFile, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
  On Error GoTo 0
End Function 'FileFolderExists

Sub Macro1()
    Dim text As String
    Dim secresult, oneresult, tworesult, mresult, dresult As String
    Dim finalresult As String
    Dim first, testlen, datelen As Integer
    
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim prfx As String
    Dim sufx As String
    Dim oName As String
    Dim nName As String
    Dim lNum As Long
      
         
    'Specify File Path from Input Screen
    sFilePath = [Source]
    
    sFilePath = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(sFilePath))
        If sFilePath = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Source folder must be entered" & vbLf & vbLf & _
           "Unable to continue with rename", vbCritical + vbExclamation
        GoTo QuickExit
    End If

    If InStr(Len(sFilePath), sFilePath, "\") = 0 Then sFilePath = sFilePath & "\"
    If Not FileFolderExists(sFilePath) Then
        MsgBox "The input folder does not appear to be valid" & vbLf & vbLf & _
           "Unable to continue with rename", vbCritical + vbExclamation
        GoTo QuickExit
    End If
    
    'Specify new suffix
    sufx = ".pdf"
    
    'Check for back slash
    If Right(sFilePath, 1) <> "\" Then
        sFilePath = sFilePath & "\"
    End If
       
    sFileName = Dir(sFilePath & "*.pdf")
   
    lNum = 0 ' File Counter
    
'   Loop through all PDF files in folder
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
    
        'Find length of File Name
        testlen = Len(sFileName)
        first = InStr(sFileName, "_")
        datelen = testlen - first
              
        If datelen = 12 Then
            secresult = Mid(sFileName, first + 1, 8)
            oneresult = Left(secresult, 4)
            mresult = Right(oneresult, 2)
            dresult = Left(oneresult, 2)
            tworesult = Right(secresult, 4)
            finalresult = tworesult & mresult & dresult
           
        ElseIf datelen = 11 Then
            secresult = Mid(sFileName, first + 1, 7)
            oneresult = Left(secresult, 3)
            mresult = Right(oneresult, 2)
            dresult = Left(oneresult, 1)
            tworesult = Right(secresult, 4)
            finalresult = tworesult & mresult & "0" & dresult
                      
        End If
          
        'Specify new prefix
        prfx = Left(sFileName, first)
        
        'Get full path and name of file
        oName = sFilePath & sFileName
        'Build new path and name
        nName = sFilePath & prfx & finalresult & sufx
        'Rename file
        Name oName As nName
      
        'Set the fileName to the next available file
        sFileName = Dir
        
        lNum = lNum + 1 ' Increment File Counter
    Loop
   
    MsgBox "File Renaming complete!" & vbLf & vbLf & lNum & " file/s renamed"
        
QuickExit:
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi KJ, I'm not a VB guru either! It took me ages to make up this code (which probably is messy and can be done better). I put things together from other places. Now I'm totally lost.

Comment: You've stated `dmmyyyy` and `ddmmyyyy`. That says the month is always 2 digits in the existing filenames. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes LesFerch. Only the d can be either dd or d.

Comment: This is not VBScript it is more likely VBA.

Comment: Hi Edited original question with new road block :)

Comment: Thanks KJ. I'll have another look. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst  improving your VBA skills, can I suggest in the interim, the Windows OS task is more suited to a batch file like this :-

ren-_dmmyyyy-test.cmd

```
@echo off

cd /d "e:\test"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
set "$OldName=%%f"
set "$y=!$OldName:~-8,-4!"
if "!$OldName:~-12,-8!" == "2023" (echo some files already renamed&&goto abort)
set "test=!$OldName:~-12,-11!"
if !test!==_ (
set "$mmdd=!$OldName:~-10,-8!0!$OldName:~-11,-10!"
echo ren "%%f"  "!$OldName:~0,-12!_!$y!!$mmdd!.pdf"
) else (
set "$mmdd=!$OldName:~-10,-8!!$OldName:~-12,-10!"
echo ren "%%f" "!$OldName:~0,-13!_!$y!!$mmdd!.pdf"
) 
)
:abort
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

**Note** the echo before the 2 ren lines, is so that you can test, that it is what is required and if happy it solves an XY problem, then remove those 2 echo's.

### Answer as VBA

based on above can be something like this

```
Private Sub SearchFiles(myDir, fn)
Dim fso As Object, myFolder As Object, myFile As Object
Dim temp As String, m As Object, NewName As String, OldName As String
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each myFile In fso.getfolder(myDir).Files
    OldFile = myFile
    temp$ = myFile.Name
    Start$ = Left(temp$, Len(temp$) - 12)
    ext = Right(temp$, 4)
    yyyy = Left(Right(temp$, 8), 4)
        dmm = Left(Right(temp$, 12), 4)
    If Left(dmm, 1) = "_" Then
        MsgBox "Name " & OldFile & " As " & Start$ & "_" & yyyy & Right(dmm, 2) & "0" & Mid(dmm, 2, 1) & ext
    Else
        MsgBox "Name " & OldFile & " As " & Start$ & yyyy & Right(dmm, 2) & Left(dmm, 2) & ext
    End If

    Next
End Sub
```

If happy that is what is wanted adjust the last two actions by remove `MsgBox "` and edit command to `Name &" "&` etc.

Comment: Cheers. I went against using RegEx. So I simplified my original attempt and got to where I wanted to go. Thanks for the input all!

Answer (score 3):

Using VBA, I prefer to use the `FileSystemObject` for all the file/folder manipulations. I also prefer early binding which is shown, although you could easily change it to late-binding if you prefer.

So I would recommend:

```
'Set References to:
'   Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
'   Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Sub RenamePDF()
    Const myDir As String = "C:\Users\ron\Desktop\pdf tests"
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, FI As File, FO As Folder
    Dim v(4), I As Long
    
Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "(^.*_)(?:(\d{1,2})(\d{2})(\d{4}))(\..*)"
End With

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
With FSO
    Set FO = FSO.GetFolder(myDir)
    For Each FI In FO.Files
        With RE
            If .Test(FI.Name) Then
                Set MC = .Execute(FI.Name)
                v(0) = MC(0).SubMatches(0)
                v(1) = MC(0).SubMatches(3)
                v(2) = MC(0).SubMatches(2)
                v(3) = Format(MC(0).SubMatches(1), "00")
                v(4) = MC(0).SubMatches(4)
                    
                    If v(4) = ".pdf" _
                        And v(1) >= 1900 And v(1) <= 9999 _
                        And v(3) >= 1 And v(3) <= 31 _
                        And v(2) >= 1 And v(2) <= 12 Then
                    
                FSO.MoveFile FI.Path, FO.Path & "\" & Join(v, "")
                
                        End If
            End If
        End With
    Next FI
End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the goal is to rename PDF files, there is no need to use Excel. Here is a straight up VBS script that does the rename:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Test")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
  fileName = oFile.Name
  If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(fileName)) = "pdf" Then
    aParts = Split(oFSO.GetBaseName(fileName),"_")
    sName = aParts(0): sDate = aParts(1)
    If Len(sDate) = 7 Then sDate = "0" & sDate
    If Len(sDate) = 8 Then
      sYear = Right(sDate, 4)
      sMonth = Mid(sDate, 3, 2)
      sDay = Left(sDate, 2)
      newName = sName & "_" & sYear & sMonth & sDay & ".pdf"
      oFile.Name = newName
    End If
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Note that the question was tagged `VBScript` and not `VBA`.

Comment: @KJ Based on the specs, joe bloggs_3152023.pdf is not valid. The input format was specified as dmmyyyy or ddmmyyyy. That is, the month is always 2 digits. If the OP would like to change the specs, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @LesFerch in which case re-tag it [tag:vba] the code in the question clearly isn't [tag:vbscript].